# Generating dynamic Tabs with multiple query post loop

Tags: loop, duplicates

I am trying to generate a dynamic tab based navigating with query post
my code is like this

```
            <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <?php
            $my_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'showposts' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'category_name' => 'Recipes'
            ));
            $x = 0;
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $x++; 
            $category = get_the_category(); 
            ?>          
            <?php if ($x == 1) { echo '<li class="active">'; } else {echo '<li>';} ?>
            <a href="#tab<?php echo $x; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile;?>     
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
              <p>Ut consectetur libero nec nulla ullamcorper lobortis pulvinar libero viverra.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
              <p>Vivamus eget velit at mauris blandit consequat vel sed ipsum.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

this is all ok and working fine, the problem is that above code can repeat any specific category. for example it can show

```
cat1     cat2     cat3    cat1   cat2
```

this is what I dont want, I need any category not duplicating again.
how to over come this problem?

just to keep in mind that in second stage I will be using rewind_post() to get the data from above categories so I want to keep the loop inline

Thank you

ok I have update my code as following

```
            <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <?php
            $my_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'showposts' => 3,
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'category_name' => 'Recipes'
            ));
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $x = $my_query->current_post + 1;  //use this to count instead
            $categories = get_the_category();
            foreach($categories as $category) {
            if ($x == 1) { echo '<li class="active">'; } else {echo '<li>';} ?>
            <a href="#tab<?php echo $x; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
            endwhile;
            ?>  
            </ul>
```

now, how do I show 4 recipes from each categories in the tab contents section

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `foreach` for the `get_the_category`

Something like:

```
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

$x = $my_query->current_post + 1;  //you can use this to count instead
$categories = get_the_category();

foreach($categories as $category) {
 if ($x == 1) ...
//rest of your output
// remember to us $category->cat_name; instead of what you have above
}
```

Comment: Sorry by mistake I update the code in wrong section, please see my comment and revised code above

Comment: On WSPE you should ask one question at a time, it's not a forum. That way it will benefit other users. To answer the second added question you need to use rewind_posts:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts